# Обход последнего прохода цикла php

Tags: php, циклы

Вот примерная схема цикла:

```
$img = array(
     [1]=>'фото 1',
     [2]=>'фото 2',
     [3]=>'фото 3',
     [4]=>'фото 4',
     [5]=>'',
    );
    $i = 1;


    while($img[$i]){
     $i++;
     echo $i;
    };
```

На практике картинки это строки, нужно вывести 4 фотографии если 5 строка пустая, и так далее(3 фото если 4 строка пустая и.т.д).

**Проблема  в том что если последняя строка пустая то он выполняет последний проход цикла и закрывается. То-есть выводит пустую строку.**

Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$img = array('фото 1','фото 2','фото 3','фото 4','');
$i = 1;

//добавьте проверку на пустоту, и как только встретится пустая строка, цикл прервется
while($img[$i] !== ""){
 $i++;
 echo $i;
};
```

Вот рабочий [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54dcce406282ada0593c64466eb4fa7935b68dd5)

Comment: Спасибо! Но оказывается всё я правильно делал, и проблема была в вёрстке)))

Comment: Никого не смущает, что `$img = array( [1]=>'фото 1', [2]=>'фото 2', [3]=>'фото 3', [4]=>'фото 4', [5]=>'' );` это не валидный синтаксис?

Comment: @Total Pusher Не смущает) Потому что это пример для понимания. И на практике совершенно другой код.

Comment: Да, поправил, спасибо

Comment: @radar4ick Ваша правка бессмысленна! Поскольку индекс объекта является важным параметром запроса, и если их убрать то суть кода теряется.

Comment: код будет работать абсолютно так же, индексация будет автоматическая, только начинаться будет с 0

Answer (score 1):

```
$img = array(
     'фото 1',
     'фото 2',
     '',
     'фото 4',
     '',
    );
    $i = 0;


    while($img[$i]){
     echo $img[$i];
     $i++;
    };
```

Результаты:

```
aaa:фото 1
aaa:фото 2
aaa:фото 3
aaa:фото 4
```

Сначала надо делать `echo $img[$i];`, а потом только счетчик прибавлять.

Comment: Сейчас это так и есть. Видите, у вас 3 выполняется хотя он пустой.

Comment: Результаты не от этого запроса. Если по примеру, то будет только первых два. Протестируйте сами

Answer (score 0):

Вот не зависимо от того где будет пустое значение будут выведены все значения масива:

```
$img = array('фото 1','фото 2','фото 3','фото 4','','фото 5','');

foreach($img as $item){ 
    if($item != ""){ //если значениэ не пустое
        echo $item . "<br>"; // выводим значение
    }
}
```

Результат:
фото 1
фото 2
фото 3
фото 4
фото 5

Comment: Я же конкретно написал что массив лишь пример, и у меня в коде это 5 строк.